# js difference between foo(), foo and function(){foo()}

Tags: javascript, function

I have a jquery dialog with a button on it (my button, not one of the dialog buttons).

After the dialog is set up I have the following bit of code:

```
$('#bar').click(foo('baz'));
```

When I load the page and make the dialog appear, foo is run(without pressing #bar).

If the code is:

```
$('#bar').click(foo);
```

or

```
$('#bar').click(function(){foo('baz')});
```

foo doesn't run.

Why is that?
Pointers to where I should RTFM, gratefully received.

Just to clarify: Why does foo run in the first instance without the button being pressed (ie upon dialog initialisation) and foo not run in the latter 2 examples.

Oh, I think I just worked it out.

In 1. the result of foo is being passed to click.
In 2. I'm still not sure.
In 3. The anon function is being passed to click.

Comment: `()` invokes a function, `foo('baz')` invokes the function `foo` with the argument `'baz'`. Very simple. The return value of `foo('baz')` is then passed to `.click()` as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't wait for the click to call `foo` :

```
$('#bar').click(foo('baz'));
```

(`foo('baz')` is executed when this line is executed, not when the user click `#bar`)

This doesn't pass the argument to `foo` :

```
$('#bar').click(foo);
```

This is probably what you need (unless `foo` builds and returns a function, which I guess it doesn't) :

```
$('#bar').click(function(){foo('baz')});
```

The fact it doesn't work may be that your element with id `bar` isn't found or you don't click it.

---

Detailed explanation :

When you execute

```
foo(bar);
```

you execute `foo` with argument `bar`.

Wen you execute

```
a = foo;
```

you give to the variable `a` the value `foo`, which may be a function or not.

When you call

```
var a = function() {foo(bar)};
```

you create a new anonymous function, which executes `foo(bar)` when called, and you gives this new function as value of the variable `a`.

When you execute

```
$('#bar').click(function(){foo('baz')});
```

you pass a new function, calling `foo('baz')` when called, as argument to `$('#bar').click(`. JQuery calls this function when you click the element with id `bar`.

Comment: Everything works. I was just curious as to why it ran without the button being pressed in one instance and not in another.

Comment: @user1925412: What do you think executes first in `bar(foo());`? I'm sure you must have passed the result of one function call to another function. It's the same for `$(...).click(foo());`.

Comment: I tried to add detailed explanation but I'm unsure of what is exactly blocking OP.

Comment: @user1925412: No worries, quite a few people seem to be confused by this... although once explained it's dead simple.

Comment: Thank you both for your time.