# What is the Difference between function and function() When I call them in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I had a question before and a person answered it very well, My code works now, But I didn't completely understand the answer. This is the coding bit that I didn't understand -

`document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = words;`

Now I already had defined function words(). My mistake was that I had written words() instead of words. So what is the difference between calling of words() and words ?

Comment: `word()` will execute the function, `word` will hold the reference to the function which you are assigning to `onclick` handler.

Comment: Well `words` *doesn't* call them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [js difference between foo(), foo and function(){foo()}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14292977/218196)

Comment: Do you know what the meaning of `var bar = foo();`  is? What the value of `bar` will be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`words` evaluates as a function.

`words()` **calls** that function and evaluates as the resulting return value.

---

The value you assign to `onclick` needs to be the function you want to get called when the click happens.

If you want the `words` function to be called, you have to assign that.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `words` and `words()` is that in the first case you are referencing the function and in the second case you are calling it

so when you do

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = words;
```

you are assigning a function `words` to the `onclick` listener, while if you do

```
 document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = words();
```

you are actually assigning the evaluated value of words to the `onclick` listener. `onclick` needs to be assigned a function which will be called when an `onclick` event happens.

Answer (score 1):

Doing:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = words;
```

this means:

put a pointer to the function and when the event fires it will call the function. When you do `words()` you call the function.